# vitest - Error: Package subpath "./utils" is not defined by "exports" in /node_modules/@vitest/runner/package.json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, vitest

seeking help with this issue while trying to use react testing library with vite:
Error: Package subpath "./utils" is not defined by "exports" in /node_modules/@vitest/runner/package.json

```
@testing-library/jest-dom: 5.17.0
@testing-library/react: 14.0.0
jsdom: 22.1.0
vite: 3.2.7
vitest: 0.34.1
react: 18.2.0
```

Files setup.js and relevant settings have been updated in vite.config.js

Tried to run basic test to verify that component loaded, but encountered the error above

Answer (score 0):

The `package.json` in `@vitest/runner@0.34.1` specifies the following:

```json
{
   "exports": {
         // ....
         "./utils": {
             "types": "./dist/utils.d.ts",
             "import": "./dist/utils.js"
       },
   }
}
```

It appears that you might be using the `require` statement which doesn't include  `import` condition name.

There could be some potential solutions to resolve this issue:

- You could create a PR for `@vitest/runner` that include a `default` field under "./utils".
- Investigate the possibility that the lack of `import` condition, it may be caused by transformation or others

Comment: Sorry, can you please elaborate on the part on "using the require statement which doesn't include import condition name."

The components/tests that we have developed are not using any require statements

Comment: Are you using any transformation tools such as Babel or SWC? It may transform `import` statement to require function call

Comment: Yup, using @babel/eslint-parser: 7.22.9